# If $f(x)=3x-2$ and $g(x)=\ln(x^2 +1)$, solve $(f\circ g)(x)=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $f(x)=3x-2$ and $g(x)=\ln(x^2 +1)$, solve $(f \circ g)(x)=1$.

Comment: Please show some effort or explain what is your difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(g(x))= 3g(x) -2 = 3\ln(x^2-1)-2=1,$$ which is

$$\ln(x^2-1)=1$$ 
Taking exponentials gives us
$$x^2-1= e$$
So we have two solutions
$$x= \pm \sqrt{e+1}$$

Comment: I think the final answer should be $\pm\sqrt{e+1}$, and not what you wrote.

Comment: Typo indeed, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I would commonly see $f\circ g$ written as $f(g(x))$ and believe this is simpler to follow notation.

Given that $f(x)=3x-2$, and $g(x)=\ln(x^2+1)$, we want when $f(\ln(x^2+1))=1$, in other words you must solve:
$$3\ln(x^2+1)-2=1$$

**HINT:** isolate the $\ln$ function, then use that $e^{\ln(k)}=k$ for any $k$